# C# Regular Express how to have this match

Tags: c#, regex, collections, match

please help me to solve the problem, thanks very much

```
string=
"
<span id="thread_aaaa" class="tsubject">
    <a href="viewthread.php?tid=12343245&amp;extra=page%3D1"> 
        WHAT I WANT TO GET1 
    </a>
</span>

<span id="thread_bbbb" class="tsubject">
    <a href="viewthread.php?tid=65456342&amp;extra=page%3D1">
        WHAT I WANT TO GET2
    </a>
</span>
"
```

i need get the value of  WHAT I WANT TO GET1 ,  WHAT I WANT TO GET2 , etc

i am using: 
`( " < span id=\"thread_)(.+?)< /a>< /span>")`, but doesn't work, help

Comment: Remove the `</a>`. Why is that there to begin with?

Comment: What does *does not work* mean? Exception? Compiler error? Wrong result?

Comment: @acheong87:  I smell an attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions..  `aaa` = opening tag; `bbb` = closing tag

Comment: Cool.  I was right; you are trying to parse html with a regex.  You should check out HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1):

For the new example string given, this would find them:

```
string str = @"
< span id=""thread_aaaa"" class=""tsubject"" >< a href=""viewthread.php?tid=12343245&extra=page%3D1"" > WHAT I WANT TO GET1 < /a >< / span>

< span id=""thread_bbbb"" class=""tsubject"">< a href=""viewthread.php?tid=65456342&extra=page%3D1"" >WHAT I WANT TO GET2</a>< /span>";

Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"href.*>(.*)< *\/a");
var matches = regex1.Matches(str);

foreach (var m in matches)
{
    var match = (Match) m;
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim()); // write the value to the console "pattern"
}

/*
Output:
WHAT I WANT TO GET1 
WHAT I WANT TO GET2
*/
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but apply to my really situation, it doesnt works for me, pls help

Comment: Are you sure the example string is exactly what you are trying to search on? Make sure there are no extra spaces or anything. For instance, if there is no space in < /a>, if it is just </a> then the regex would need to be "href.*>(.*)<\/a" in that case.

Comment: my str is an html string which download using 
                             str = client.DownloadString("http:// www.abc.com"); but in your case you use @ symbol, i can't get anything, help

Comment: got it, maybe there are many <href>, i use this, it works!  Regex regex1 = new Regex("<span id=\"thread.*>(.*)</a"); thank you so much,Chris

Comment: That's great Lam, glad it worked! If you could mark mine as the answer that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex you are looking for is:

```
(?<=aaa)(.*)(?=bbb)
```

// Matches any characters between the 2 strings aaa and bbb